# How to capture packets from Java sockets using wireshark?

Tags: java, sockets, wireshark

I am using the standard(hello-world) Server-Client Socket application in java but instead of just sending it once the client program sends to "hello world" message for a number of times(for loop). 
When i open wireshark and select the Ethernet interface (It shows Realtek something Gigabit Ethernet) i can see all the packets.
in the filter bar when i type

```
tcp.port == 443
```

It displays the packets.

I have the server socket open at 61000 and i know that they are tcp.
but when i type

```
tcp.port == 61000
```

nothing shows up. I want to check contents of packets that are sent by sockets.
I am using
Windows 7
Java 8 
Eclipse Neon

Comment: Well, which is it, 443 or 61000? Almost certainly your server is listening on port 443.

Comment: More details needed. Are you running client and server on the same machine? And if so, are you using "localhost" as the IP address?

Comment: using localhost with port 61000. @JamesKPolk I can see traffic for 443 (when i click links in web brower) but not for 61000